# How can I get "for loop" to work properly?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I want to impute missing values with (upper value + lower value)/2.
If column "A" has NaN, I want to calculate like above and then put the value to the next column "B".
In my original dataset, I don't know how many NaNs. So I should check how many NaNs are there in a row.
I think my problem is the 'for loop'.
I tried to solve this whole day, but I couldn't.
Please check my code and give me some advice.
Thank you so much for your work and time.
Here is the sample dataset and my code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [2,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [11,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN],
              [np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [np.NaN,np.NaN],
              [8,np.NaN]],columns=list('AB'))

for r in range(df.shape[0]): 
    if math.isnan(df.A[r]) == True:
        nan_find = True
        have_nan = False
        start_row = r
        while nan_find == True:
            r = r + 1 
            if math.isnan(df.A[r]) == True:
                nan_find = True
                have_nan = True
            else:
                end_row = r-1
                nan_find = False
                r = r - 1
        for start_row in range(start_row, end_row):
            if start_row == 0:
                df.B[start_row] = (df.A[end_row+1])/2
            elif (start_row == df.shape[0]) | (end_row == df.shape[0]):
                df.B[start_row] = (df.A[start_row-1])/2
            else:
                df.B[start_row] = (df.A[start_row-1] + df.A[end_row+1])/2 
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: It's bad form to compare `bool` values to `True` or `False`.  Just use them directly, e.g. instead of `if x == True:`, instead use `if x:`.  Comparing a known `bool` to `True` makes no more sense than comparing the result of a comparison to `True`, e.g. `if (((x == True) == True) == True) == True:`  Just use `if x:` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. However, I don't understand your recommend. I'm so sorry for that. Because I studied python by myself, my code skills and knowledge are very low and terrible. Anyway, thank you  so much for your time and work.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, it's just a mistake that an experienced coder wouldn't make.  Basically just get rid of all the `== True`, *unless* the value being tested is not a `bool` (i.e., if it may be something other than `True` or `False`, and you're testing more than just its truth value, but that's an unusual case).  For example, `nan_find` can only be `True` or `False`, so change `while nan_find == True:` to `while nan_find:` Similarly, `math.isnan()` returns either `True` or `False`, so change `if math.isnan(df.A[r]) == True:` to `if math.isnan(df.A[r]):`  It's tighter and clearer.

Comment: There's also an implication when you write `if x == True:`, which is that you don't care about the truth value of `x`, but instead only care if it's exactly equal to `True`, and that it may have some other value that is regarded as true such as `123` or `"abc"`, and you do *not* want to evaluate the `if` condition if it has any of those other values.  So in a sense, it's an incorrect comment in cases where you actually mean `if x:`

Comment: Oh~ I got you. Thank you so much for your kind explanation. Your recommendation was very helpful to me. Thank you again and have a great day!!

Comment: I solved the problem. After changing my code, it looked very clear and easy. So, I could fine the problem easily. Thank you again.